# Why does radio sometimes oscillate in and off tune while driving a car

Tags: radio

Sometimes while listening to radio on a car I notice the tuning will periodically go off tune (you hear just noise) and back in. Apparently it depends on the car's position, i.e. if I stop on a "in tune region" it stays this way and vice-versa.

Is it "shadow" caused by buildings? But then why periodic? Is it some kind of interference with other radio waves? How does it work? Why don't we notice a similar phenomenon with light? Or is it something particular to FM encoding?

Comment: I've always attributed it to handoff between repeaters or something

Comment: Multipath, topography, ...

Comment: I've always noticed this effect to be persistent in specific spots. My favorite parking space at work happens to be one of them, though mostly I notice it near intersections where many power lines converge. This may be an effect of confirmation bias though, since I took a guess at the cause before I started paying any attention to the data.

Comment: notice the nulls: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_(wave_propagation)#/media/File:Two_sources_interference.gif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're talking about [FM radio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FM_broadcasting), which (at least in the US) is broadcast in the 87.5 to 108.0 MHz band, with wavelength of about 3 meters. "FM" means "frequency modulation"; the audio information is encoded as variations of the carrier frequency.

Although FM radio is fairly resistant to interference, it is vulnerable to something called [multipath inteference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipath_interference), which happens when the radio signal takes multiple paths from the transmitter to the receiver. Depending on the lengths of the two paths, the signals can [interfere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_(wave_propagation)), where the peak of one signal coincides with the trough of the other signal, canceling each other out.

Classic multipath interference is heard while driving a car, where motion changes the lengths of the two (or more) paths, periodically canceling and reinforcing the signal. In fringe reception areas you can even get this effect from an airplane overhead, where one path bounces off the airplane and interferes with the direct path, fading in and out even though you may not be moving.

Presumably, the parking spot with no reception mentioned in the comments is where the multiple paths (probably one bouncing off a building) exactly cancel. The solution would be to move the car, the building, or the transmitter. Or, choose a new favorite station.

Comment: Exactly. It is like you are driving through a standing wave pattern - reception is OK near the antinode but poor near the node.